# Postfix: How to check from what script the message has been sent?

Tags: postfix

Does postfix know the origin script that sent the email somehow? Is it possible to track the web scripts that sent the email?

I am on a web farm having sites A, B, C. 
Site A has scripts a.php, site B has b.py, and site C has c.pl script. These scripts are producing email on user interaction.

What is the best way so I can track the origin scripts of the emails? 
I would like to eliminate the possible spam and to warn the web site administrators, they are having problems with email spam.

Comment: With php you can use http://php.net/manual/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.log But it will track only mails that would be send with php mail() function

Comment: great, may be that any programming language has similar hook to detect and log the script that sent the email based on the mail function; thought it would be nice to know if the postfix knows the details, or may fetch the details based on some pre-settings.  It is some kind of linux process P1 forked linux process P2, and P2 knows about P1 then.

Comment: Actually, the process that is responsible for the mailq may have the information who sent the mail, (or email origin details)

Comment: No, postfix don't know anything about "application layer" and from which script you have sent an email. It doesn't bother him. It will only track client ip address.

Comment: You could require authentication to postfix and give each webmaster their own credentials.  *or* you could require each webmaster have a particular header in their email *or* you could write an auditd rule to log which script talked to your postfix port, but this is a noisy heavy handed approach, *or* you could have a different virtual instance for each webmaster via `master.cf`, you can read up on how to do that, as implementation varies wildly with your network configuration.

Comment: Of course you could. But the question was - 'is the postfix able to track such information'

Comment: And the right answer - no, it can't and moreover it shouldn't. Unique header for each webmaster doesn't solve the main issue - "How to find the script". The same things for master.cf case.

Comment: citation: **One of the key aspects of Postfix is that it is designed to be a modular package**. It may be some script detector modules exits, but I am not aware of it. BTW, I like the idea of audit rule ( @Aaron ) to log which script talked to the postfix port, I don't get this is a bad idea at all, although it is not quite postfix way doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup postfix to allow only authenticated users to send emails. 
Then you can manage limits by users, and of course follow each mail be the sender user.

It could be that your clients won't like it, they will have to adjust their scripts but it's much better than your IP get blacklisted and all mails go straight to the spam folders.

Comment: it's not the answer to the question. Because you never get information about what script was used

Comment: Each script can have a different username.

Comment: OMG. It's not a solution at all.

Comment: Any solution will have to be some change in each of the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to setup postmulti - then you can maintain multiple distinct configurations (and also stuff like rate limiting per service) per service.

this is also easier than authentication (if it's on the same host/area and access to the postfix is granted for everyone).

downside: each postmulti listens on another port - but each serious client can adjust the port of the server.

the name of the postmulti instance is also in the logs (and also the statistics are written per instance) - this makes it very easy to provide a distinct view on a per service base

Comment: The same problem. With multi instance - you can't find out what script has been used.

Comment: setting up postmulti with different ports will obviously show from what application / script the traffic has been generated. it's just required that the scripts use their designated postmulti instance (which is nothing more than a whole dedicated instance). it's just less complex than setting up auth. additional modules in postfix don't detect any kind of scripts - it's not tcp analysis (the whole socket is always in hands of postfix). best way trying to detect a script is some weirdness in the headers.

Comment: Each scripts? And what would be if you will have 2kk of scripts on the server?

Comment: the question intended to distinct the inputs per script/language and not per customer. so there is a quite limited number of possible inputs. when having many different users/customers on the same relay you can still go with authentication. if you want to track down heavy users easily it's a little harder then as you've to provide log analysis that measures over a given timespan (which is possible but memory intensive when you're using tools like logstash).